# Validation in forms with angular: how to show specific errors for different invalid cases?

Tags: html, angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which validates all the inputs. For, say, 'username' input I want to make sure it's a required field first and second that its length isn't less than 2 or more than 10 (or fits another pattern I use).

I'd like to show an error when either validation fails. How do I do this if I want to show a specific error for each case case? For example: if the input is empty show 'required', if the value is wrong show 'invalid'. Here's my code:

component:

```
companyNamePattern = "^[a-z0-9_-]{8,15}$";
pwdPattern = "^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,12}$";
emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";

this.addCompForm = fb.group({
  'companyName':     [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5),Validators.maxLength(20)])],
  'companyPassword': [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5),Validators.maxLength(20)])],
  'companyEmail':    [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.email])]
})
```

html:

```
<form [formGroup] ="addCompForm" (ngSubmit) = "addCompany(addCompForm.value)">
    <p>Enter the company name:</p>
    <input type="text" formControlName="companyName" >
    <div class="alert" *ngIf="!addCompForm.controls['companyName'].valid && addCompForm.controls['companyName'].touched" >{{nameAlert}}</div>

    <p>Enter the company password:</p>
    <input type="text" formControlName="companyPassword">
    <div class="alert"  *ngIf="!addCompForm.controls['companyPassword'].valid && addCompForm.controls['companyPassword'].touched " >{{passAlert}}</div>

    <p>Enter the company email:</p>
    <input type="text" formControlName="companyEmail">
    <div class="alert"  *ngIf="!addCompForm.controls['companyEmail'].valid && addCompForm.controls['companyEmail'].touched " >{{emailAlert}}</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-container">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!addCompForm.valid">
            <i class="material-icons">done</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: anyone?........

Answer (score 0):

```
*ngIf="addCompForm.get('companyName').hasError('required')
```

add this to make required field and

```
*ngIf="addCompForm.get('companyName').hasError('minLength')
```

add this for making minLength and same as for max length .hasErro('maxlength')

Comment: thats not working... here the code: <div *ngIf="addCompForm.get('companyName').hasError('required')" >required</div>
        <div *ngIf="addCompForm.get('companyName').hasError('minLength')" >min</div>
        <div *ngIf="addCompForm.get('companyName').hasError('maxLength')" >max</div>

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snackbar-rer1ey?file=app/app.component.ts  see this..it works on stackblitz..